# Mockito: How to properly mock a List of Spring Services

Tags: spring, mockito

I have the following Spring Service class that I'm trying to test with Mockito:

```
@Service
public class ObjectExportService {

    @Autowired
    protected List<SecuredService<? extends SecuredObject>> securedServices;

    public void doStuff() {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.securedServices.size(); i++){
            SecuredService<? extends SecuredObject> securedSrv = this.securedServices.get(i);
            //this access works
        }
        for (SecuredService<? extends SecuredObject> securedSrv : this.securedServices) { //this access does not work
            
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Test class for that service:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ObjectExportServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ObjectExportService objectExportService;

    @Mock
    protected List<SecuredService<? extends SecuredObject>> securedServices;

    @Test
    public void testDoStuff(){
        objectExportService.doStuff();
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I get a NullpointerException, but only in the for-each loop.

First I assumed is a similar problem as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483176/mockito-mocking-an-arraylist-that-will-be-looped-in-a-for-loop) thread:
I have Mocked the List and would therefore need to mock the `iterator()` call.

The solutions provided in that thread didn't work for me, because I am actually autowiring a List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33302741/12263454) solution in another thread. Simply changing the `@Mock` to `@Spy` resolved the issue for me:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ObjectExportServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ObjectExportService objectExportService;

    @Spy  // <-- change here
    protected List<SecuredService<? extends SecuredObject>> securedServices;

    @Test
    public void testDoStuff(){
        objectExportService.doStuff();
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```